# How to construct a wheeling system for soccer betting?

Tags: combinatorics, gambling

A single bet consists of predicting the result of $n$ games, where
each game has $3$ different possible outcomes: win, draw, loss.

Given a set of guesses for each game, I want to calculate the minimum number of bets that can guarantee the second prize (i.e., hit $n-1$ games).

I don't need a detailed explanation on how to achieve that, just where to look for.

Comment: I would not know "where to look."  It might not be too difficult to work out the "wheel" that you ask for, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is also known as a [*ternary covering code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code). Your case is often referred to in the literature as the Football pools problem. The Wikipedia article also has the best known bounds for $n\le 14$. See the $R=1$ column of [this table](http://old.sztaki.hu/~keri/codes/3_tables.pdf) for citations on where those bounds cam form.